# How do I get the value of a dynamically generated control in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the value of items in a dynamically made combobox from a separate event. I need to put the value the user chose into a string, but I can't find a way to do it. Here's an example.

```
            ComboBox player1Role = new ComboBox();
        player1Role.Width = 100;
        player1Role.Items.Add("Top");
        player1Role.Items.Add("Jungle");
        player1Role.Items.Add("Mid");
        player1Role.Items.Add("Bot");
        player1Role.Items.Add("Support");
        player1Role.Items.Add("Fill");
        player1Role.Location = new Point(200, 200);
```

And then in the following click event, I need to get the value they selected:

```
        private void CreateParty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBox player1SelectedRole = (ComboBox)Controls["player1Role"];
        string player1roleString = player1SelectedRole.Items[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(player1roleString);
    }
```

That code just gives me an exception saying player1SelectedRole was empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the control by its name, but you didn't assign a name to the control.

```
player1Role.Name = "player1Role";
```

Also, I think `player1SelectedRole.Items[0]` is always going to select the first item regardless of which one is actually selected. Check out `player1SelectedRole.SelectedItem` instead.

Comment: About the SelectedItem your right, however I'm still getting the same result even when I assign a name.

Comment: Ah, your correct, sorry. Your .name fixed it, my problem was I was looking for the control in form1 rather than the actual thing it was attached to, hence why it displayed null. Changing that and adding your .name fixed it, thanks for the help!